# How do you use the arguments keyword in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, arguments

In JavaScript, the `arguments` keyword is useful for getting information about a function's arguments. It's 'array-like' in that it can be indexed like an array, but `Array.isArray` will return `false` on it.

I'm trying to use `arguments.length` in a function I am exporting via `module.exports` like so:

```
module.exports.foo = (args) => {
    console.log(arguments.length); 
}
```

**The problem:** arguments.length **always** prints 5. When I actually go to print `arguments` itself, I see that it is an array-like object containing the following:

0: an array of things I'm exporting from the current module (in this case, an array of all of my functions.

1: the `require` function

2: an object containing information about the current module, like what it's exporting, the including module, file paths, etc.

3: he path to the current module

4: the path to the directory containing the current module

The problem is `arguments` in this context doesn't work like I expect it to. No matter how many arguments I pass in to the function call, it always prints 5.

How do you properly use the `arguments` keyword in Node.js exported functions?

Comment: Either use a `function` instead, or use argument rest syntax instead, `= (...args) => { console.log(args.length)`

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it was an arrow function vs function issue! Thanks. That helped. Using the argument rest syntax now.